# Как обрезать строку с html первые 1000 символов

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как в PHP обрезать строку, оставив только первые 1000 символов? 
**При этом строка содержит HTML теги и нужно обрезать строку без учёта тегов.**(т.е. просто substr, не подходит) Т.е. 1000 символов должно остаться текста, а сколько символов будет занимать HTML не важно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов

1. Пересмотреть задачу, выкасить весь html и обрезать

   $test = strip_tags($test);
   $test = substr($test,0,1000);
2. Ввести тэг описания допустим `<cat>` или bb-код и обрезать по нему `[cat]`.
3. Обрезать не по символам а по количеству слов к примеру с тем условием что бы тэг обязательно закрывался после.

вам подойдёт только способ под номером 1,2-в, если обрезать автоматом то с вероятностью в 98% вы обрежите закрывающие теги, и будете фиксить баги пожизненно.